# Is there a VirtualDub alternative which works with DirectShow filters?

Tags: virtualdub, directshow

The question says it all: I'm looking for a VirtualDub alternative which can work with video files if there's only a DirectShow filter available (and not a VFW filters as VirtualDub requires)

Answer (score 3):

What particular format do you need to read?

[Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) is a really nice video processor along the same lines as VirtualDub, but with much wider codec and container support. It doesn't use DirectShow though, or even VfW; it is instead supplied with support for many formats built in.

Answer (score 2):

Another freeware product that gets good reviews is [Pinnacle VideoSpin](http://videospin.com/redesign/tutorials/featured-tutorials_FreeVideoEditing.asp).
I quote from the review [Gizmo](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-video-editor.htm):

> Another major contendor in the world of video editors is a corporation named Pinnacle. Pinnacle is a software company that
>   creates high quality video editing
>   software for professionals and
>   individuals alike. Recently they
>   introduced a freeware program called
>   Pinnacle Video Spin. The software
>   itself is very flashy and contains
>   many usefull features. However, many
>   features are blocked and even omitted
>   in the free version. For this reason
>   it is not my most highly rated
>   software. But for the user who is just
>   looking to do simple editing, the
>   program works fine. It comes packed
>   with many preinstalled titles and
>   credits.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may not like it if you are use to VirtualDub and the advanced features however-

Windows Movie Maker...

I used it recently on Windows 7 (the version you download from Live) and was surprisingly impressed for a free product. It did what I needed and I converted it to DIVX from WMV when I was done.

I can't think of anything that would work with the Direct Show filters better!

Answer (score 1):

You can use VirtualDub with the DirectShow input plugin ( http://forums.virtualdub.org/index.php?act=ST&f=7&t=12664 ) but it works better if you use the specific input plugins + the needed VFW codecs that you can find in ffdshow-tryout